# CSS Shadow Box inset

Tags: css

I thought I understood how CSS shadow-box works, apperently I don't.

Can anybody give me a visual descritpion of why the `<hr/>` looks like it does here?
Look at style 13 : https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 700px;
  float: center;
}

hr.style1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style2 {
  border-top: 3px double #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style3 {
  border-top: 1px dashed #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style4 {
  border-top: 1px dotted #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style5 {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 2px dashed #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style6 {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 2px dotted #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style7 {
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

hr.style8 {
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

hr.style8:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

hr.style9 {
  border-top: 1px dashed #8c8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
}

hr.style10 {
  border-top: 1px dotted #8c8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}

hr.style11 {
  height: 6px;
  background: url(http://ibrahimjabbari.com/images/hr-11.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  border: 0;
}

hr.style12 {
  height: 6px;
  background: url(http://ibrahimjabbari.com/images/hr-12.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  border: 0;
}

hr.style13 {
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #8c8b8b inset;
}

hr.style14 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
}

hr.style15 {
  border-top: 4px double #8c8b8b;
  text-align: center;
}

hr.style15:after {
  content: '\002665';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #8c8b8b;
  font-size: 18px;
}

hr.style16 {
  border-top: 1px dashed #8c8b8b;
}

hr.style16:after {
  content: '\002702';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  left: 40px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #8c8b8b;
  font-size: 18px;
}

hr.style17 {
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
  text-align: center;
}

hr.style17:after {
  content: '§';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #8c8b8b;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

hr.style18 {
  height: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8c8b8b;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

hr.style18:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -31px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #8c8b8b;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<hr class="style1">
<br>
<hr class="style2">
<br>
<hr class="style3">
<br>
<hr class="style4">
<br>
<hr class="style5">
<br>
<hr class="style6">
<br>
<hr class="style7">
<br>
<hr class="style8">
<br>
<hr class="style9">
<br>
<hr class="style10">
<br>
<hr class="style11">
<br>
<hr class="style12">
<br>
<hr class="style13">
<br>
<hr class="style14">
<br>
<hr class="style15">
<br>
<hr class="style16">
<br>
<hr class="style17">
<br>
<hr class="style18">
```

If the shadow-box is insetted with the very first value (for top right) being 0px? (`box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #8c8b8b inset;`)
How is it possible that the gradient color START at the top?

Makes no sense to me and the more I read the documentation the more confuseed I get because it should not be doing that (as I understand).

PS: I followed a link to style some `<hr/>`elements and to learn from the experience so that I can create my own custom ones.I came to style 13 from that link and it looks very cool. However I cannot figure out why it works with that CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If not specified (default), the shadow is assumed to be a drop shadow (as if the box were raised above the content).
The presence of the inset keyword changes the shadow to one inside the frame (as if the content was depressed inside the box). Inset shadows are drawn inside the border (even transparent ones), above the background, but below content."

This is the reason I guess. Might be this is helpful for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow